# How to insert the value in a listbox from a database

Tags: php, session, listbox

I need some help with my code. I'm fetching the data from a database as I am storing the data in a `$_SESSION` array. Now I would like to insert the data in a listbox but I have got a problem with insert the data in a listbox.

When I try this:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["gender"]); ?>'>
    <option value="unknown"></option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

It will not insert the data in a listbox as the listbox show there is no data have been insert in a listbox.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
//print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["gender"]); ?>'>
        <option value="unknown"></option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
```

Here is what the `$_SESSION` array show:

```
Array
(
    [loggedin] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [username] => myusername
    [firstname] => Robert
    [lastname] => Jones
    [email] => xxx.xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com
    [gender] => Male
    [states] => United Kingdom
)
```

Can you please show me an example how I can insert the data in a listbox using with php echo that I'm pulling the data from the `$_SESSION` array?

Thank you.

Comment: `select` __does not__ have `value` attribute.

Comment: Oh right. So how I can insert the data in a option value using with php echo $_SESSION?

Comment: You have to generate this select within PHP if you want to do it, or jQuery and Ajax

Comment: I dont know how I could do that. If you could show me an example that would be great. I only want to select the data in the listbox that matched with the data from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would generate this select via PHP

```
$html = '<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control">';
$values = array('unknown', 'Male', 'Female');
foreach($values as $v){
    $selected = '';
    if($v == 'unknown'){
        $title = '';
    }else{
        $title = $v;
    }
    if($v == $_SESSION["gender"]){
        $selected = "selected";
    }
    $html .= "<option $selected value='$v'>$title</option>";
}
$html .= "</select>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for this as I can see it works great!